# Angular: Setting routerLink queryParams as component property results in error

Tags: angular, routerlink, angular-routerlink

When I bind `queryParams` using `routerLink` in Angular2, I am getting this error:

> [ERROR] Exception while trying to serialize the value

This error is shown when I inspect the DOM. The links simply do not show at all on the page, so this was my only way of debugging since there were no errors in the console either.

[screenshot of DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN22g.png)

Component Code

```
export class FormatUrlLinkComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('url') apiUrl: string;
  @Input('text') linkText: string;
  validUrl: {
    url: string,
    query: object
  } = {
    url: '',
    query: {}
  };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Format url into a valid url for routerLink
    this.validUrl = queryString.parseUrl(this.apiUrl);
    console.log(this.validUrl.query);
  }

}
```

Template Code

```
<a [routerLink]="validUrl.url" [queryParams]="validUrl.query"></a>
```

When I do a `console.log(this.validUrl.query)` I am seeing the following:

```
{Ntt: "welded"}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What is  `Params` defined as for `query: Params`? You define `url` as a `string` and `query` as type `Params`. Where did you create that `Params` type?

Comment: That error is detached from context. Error message tells me as much about your problem as current moon phase.

Comment: Sorry `query` is of type `object`. I forgot to update this. It still produces the same error. That error is attached to the `[queryParams]` in the DOM when I inspect the page. Since it doesn't give me an error in the console, but it just simply doesn't show the links so this was my only way of debugging @Antoniossss

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason, I solved it by doing this:

```
// Format url into a valid url for routerLink
const validUrl = queryString.parseUrl(this.apiUrl);
this.validUrl.url = validUrl.url;
this.validUrl.query = validUrl.query;
```

Not sure why I had to assign the value to a variable and then assign the two values from that variable to the one being used in the template, but this fixed it.